# BST preorder to postorder using stack without recursion

Tags: stack, binary-search-tree, preorder, postorder

BST given preorder, how to get the postorder using stack without recursion? Java is prefered! Thanks!

Following is my answer but failed to pass 2 hidden test case...Anyone can help? Thanks!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
public class Solution {
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cur = "";
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        cur = sc.nextLine();
        Integer curIn = Integer.valueOf(cur);
        if(stack.isEmpty() || stack.peek() > curIn){
            stack.push(curIn);
        }else{
            Integer root = null; 
            Integer max = stack.peek();
            while(!stack.isEmpty() && (stack.peek() < curIn || (root != null && stack.peek() < root))){
                if(root != null)
                    System.out.println(root);
                root = stack.pop();
                max = Math.max(root, max);
            }
            stack.push(root);
            stack.push(curIn);
        }
    }
    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The input format is only one node in each line

Comment: It'd be worth showing some sample input. Can any nodes be null?